# How can I invoke a Firebase Cloud Function with AppCheck enforced from an app extension using Firebase Swift SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-app-check

I am working on an iOS app extension which requires invoking a Firebase cloud function through Firebase Swift SDK . Please note that I have enforced AppCheck in my NodeJS cloud function. I have also registered both the app extension and app host bundle ids to allow for Firebase App Check Capability as well.

I have already initialized AppCheck in the app delegate of my app host and view controller of my app extension (not sure if this is correct)

```
 let providerFactory = DeviceCheckProviderFactory()
AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
```

I have read somewhere that AppCheck is not supported within an app extension environment, if it is the case what would be the best way to handle invoking the cloud function whilst transmitting the Appcheck token from within the app extension?